# generating continuous 'id' field in a column for all dataframes where I have a list of data frames

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, sequence

I have a list of 4/5 data frames with a blank column 'id', I want to generate a cumulative sequence across these data frames.

I tried something like this but its not working.
f is my list of data frames

```
for i in range(1,len(f)):
    print(f[1]['id'])
    for  row in f[i]['id']: 
        f[i]=f[i].assign(id=numpy.arange(1,len(f)+1))
```

I want an output data frames like
f[0]:

| id | table |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abc |
| 2 | def |

f[1]:

| id | table |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | abc |
| 4 | def |

f[2]:

| id | table |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | abc |
| 6 | def |

so on..

Please help.New to python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple loop approach could be:

```
dfs = [df1, df2]

start = 0
for d in dfs: 
    stop = start + len(d)
    d['id'] = range(start, stop)
    start = stop
```